# Find out which script tag throws error

Tags: javascript, onerror

The javascript **onerror** event let me know some information about the error, like line number, column number and url. It also gives a message to help find out what happened (e.g. reference error, syntax error)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

However, the line number starts at 1 inside the script in which the error happened. It is not the line number of the document. For example, if I have 4 script tags (with code inside, not external references) inside my html file, and the onerror says that line 2 threw an error, it could have been line 2 of any of the 4 script tags.

Is there a way to know which of the script tags has the code that fired the error? I have more than one script tag in my document and it takes long to check each of then when I have only the line number and a generic message.

Comment: Doesn't the second argument tell you that? `source: URL of the script where the error was raised (string)`

Comment: the url gives me only the name of the html file

Comment: Why do you have four separate `<script>` tags in one HTML file? And can't you just log outputs and set breakpoints to find the culprit?

Comment: I am using javaFX webview to load some HTML. The scripts must be loaded inside the HTML dynamically, not referenced, for security purposes. The script can't be in external files. I tried output logging, but it is still time consuming. That's why identifying the script could quickly solve it for me... I was going to print the line based on its number! Is there a way to use breakpoints inside the JavaFX webview?